# What's the idiomatic way to rotate a list of points in np?

Tags: python, numpy

Here's a code I use to rotate a 2D vector by 100 degrees:

```
theta = np.deg2rad(100)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
R = np.matrix([[c, -s], [s, c]])
V = np.transpose(np.matrix([[1., 1.]]))
Z = np.matmul(R, V)
```

Is there a built in function for that in numpy?

Comment: 9 radians? the way your code is implemented that's 9 degrees... 9 radians would be pretty weird anyway...

Comment: I don't think numpy has a function for that. You could easily turn your code into a function for yourself to use though.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm sorry, that was a typo, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Have a look at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider what you did as idiomatic. If you want to be fancy you can use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler).

Avoid numpy.matrix, use regular arrays and array.dot(another).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in fixed size small vectors I would hardcode the result of the matrix operations and leave it dependent on the cos() and sin(). If the matrix are small but a push with the math would be welcome I recommend you to try [wxMaxima](https://wxmaxima-developers.github.io/wxmaxima/) to get an analytical result to hardcode. On the other hand, if this is an example targeting bigger vectors I would follow Mihai's suggestion and go for scipy.